# Retain ESRI symbology in Mapinfo TAB

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, cartography, mapinfo, tab

Is there anyway to retain/easily transfer symbology from ESRI to Mapinfo? The only process I found was posted in 2010 - https://groups.google.com/group/mapinfo-l/browse_thread/thread/883223ff4ae56809 and it is rather convoluted and supposed to be unreliable.

ArcGIS 10 and Mapinfo 11 are the core programs.

This is related to [Converting ArcGIS style (symbology) to font for MapInfo/OpenGeo?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28806/is-it-possible-to-convert-an-esri-style-sheet-to-a-font-set) and [Creating summary table of symbology of all datasets in multiple MXDs?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27807/create-a-summary-table-of-the-symbology-of-all-datasets-in-multiple-mxds) as possible workarounds.

Comment: Are you consider only out-of-the box solutions?

Comment: Yes even a solution that costs us money as it will save time and money in the long run.

Comment: @AlexMarkov -yes a commercial solution will be ok if necessary. Do you have one?

Comment: Actually not a solution but if you have no other options take a look at [FME](http://www.safe.com/fme/fme-technology/fme-desktop/overview/) - there you can write styles to MapInfo format using [MapInfoStyler](http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Transformers/FMETransformers.htm#transformers/mapinfostyler.htm) transformer. But it has much to be done here in order to get results... ANother way is to use MapBasic to apply you custom styles to result data. You have to develop styles in MapInfo also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically this was not possible but figured out a roundabout way to get the result. See [arcgis python script to tool issue](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30763/arcgis-python-script-to-tool-issue) for final result.

Other questions to get to this stage are

[Converting ArcGIS style (symbology) to font for MapInfo/OpenGeo?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28806/is-it-possible-to-convert-an-esri-style-sheet-to-a-font-set)

[Retain ESRI symbology in Mapinfo TAB](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25820/retain-esri-symbology-in-mapinfo-tab)

and

[Creating summary table of symbology of all datasets in multiple MXDs?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27807/create-a-summary-table-of-the-symbology-of-all-datasets-in-multiple-mxds)

Answer (score 2):

These folks have a product that claims to be able to convert between them: http://www.dataeast.com/en/TABReader.asp - to quote:

> With TAB Reader tools you will be able to import TAB symbology to ArcGIS, batch convert TAB symbology from TAB files to ArcGIS layer (.lyr) files, as well as import MapInfo workspaces (.wor) to ArcGIS ArcMap documents (.mxd).

---

There's also a thread on the MapInfo mailing list archives that may be of interest as it references possible tools (it is ~6 years old though) - http://www.mail-archive.com/mapinfo-l@lists.directionsmag.com/msg30177.html

Comment: Thanks. This goes tab-to-ESRI but I really need ESRI/SHP -- to -- Mapinfo TAB symbology (not just data).