# Converting ArcGIS style (symbology) to font for MapInfo/OpenGeo?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, mapinfo, style, boundless-suite, font

This is related to [Retain ESRI symbology in Mapinfo TAB](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25820/retain-esri-symbology-in-mapinfo-tab)

As a workaround I am wondering if I can save all my ESRI symbology from the lyr files created using the script below to an ESRI style sheet and then convert that to a font set which can be opened in mapinfo/opengeo?

[image: Screenshot]

The image above shows some of the [complex] symbology that we have in our ESRI mxd's that need to go into Mapinfo and/or Opengeo to be available via WMS.

Tests show that KML created from the lyr files handle the symbology better than tab but not every time.

Code so far...

```py
import arcpy, string, datetime, shutil, os
import arcpy.mapping as MAP

#Read input parameters from script tool
MXDList = string.split(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0), ";")
ProjectPath = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

#MXDList=r'P:\2012\183_TownPlanning_Symbology\Working\test.mxd'
#ProjectPath=r'P:\2012\183_TownPlanning_Symbology\Working'

count=0
#Loop through each MXD and print
#for MXDPath in MXDList:
#MXDFile=r'P:\2012\183_TownPlanning_Symbology\Working\Strategic_Plan_Ravenshoe_8.mxd'
count=count+1
print count
##try:
mxd=arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(MXDFile)
outPath = ProjectPath+'\\'+mxd.filePath[mxd.filePath.rfind('\\')+1:mxd.filePath.rfind('.')]
os.mkdir(outPath)
msd = outPath+'.msd'
dfList = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)
for df in dfList:
#arcpy.mapping.ConvertToMSD(mxd, msd, df, "NORMAL", "NORMAL")
#arcpy.AddMessage(str(count)+'...' +str(outPath)+'...'+'\n')
    lyrList=arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", df)
    outPath = ProjectPath+'\\'+mxd.filePath[mxd.filePath.rfind('\\')+1:mxd.filePath.rfind('.')]+'\\'+str(df.name)
    os.mkdir(outPath)
    for lyrFile in lyrList:
        if lyrFile.isFeatureLayer == True:
            if lyrFile.visible == True:
                arcpy.AddMessage(str(lyrFile)+' is visible')
                print str(lyrFile)+' is visible...exporting dataset'
                outFileN=str(arcpy.ValidateTableName(lyrFile.longName[lyrFile.longName.rfind('\\')+1:]))
                try:
                    arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(lyrFile.dataSource, outPath, outFileN)
                    arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management(lyrFile,outPath+'\\'+outFileN+'.lyr', "ABSOLUTE")
                    arcpy.LayerToKML_conversion(outPath+'\\'+outFileN+'.lyr', outPath+'\\'+outFileN+'.kmz')
                except:
                    print 'Exists...continuing'


        arcpy.AddMessage(str(lyrFile)+' is visible')
        print str(lyrFile)+' is not visible'
##except:
##    errorM=arcpy.GetMessages()
##    arcpy.AddMessage(str(count)+str(errorM)+'\n continuing...\n')
##    print errorM
##    #MAP.PrintMap(MXD, printer)
#Remove variable reference to file
del mxd, msd
```

BTW// I tried the msd route (change to .zip and open the xml) but it is very convoluted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically this was not possible but figured out a roundabout way to get the result. See [arcgis python script to tool issue](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30763/arcgis-python-script-to-tool-issue) for final result.

I am using Arc2Earth community edition to convert each lyr to sld. It is manual but quick.

Other questions to get to this stage are

[Converting ArcGIS style (symbology) to font for MapInfo/OpenGeo?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28806/is-it-possible-to-convert-an-esri-style-sheet-to-a-font-set)

[Retain ESRI symbology in Mapinfo TAB](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25820/retain-esri-symbology-in-mapinfo-tab)

and

[Creating summary table of symbology of all datasets in multiple MXDs?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27807/create-a-summary-table-of-the-symbology-of-all-datasets-in-multiple-mxds)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure sure if the GeoCat bridge provides this exact functionality but its worth checking out.

http://geocat.net/bridge/

Comment: Thanks. This is quite an expensive option (thus currently not viable) and will only work for a WMS based solution...the primary need is conversion to tab/mapinfo symbology and wms is only if converting to mapinfo isn't practical.