# arcgis python script to tool issue

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1

I have a script to investigate mxd's and save them as lyr symbology/kmz and sld which works fine when run from the .py but does not run when used as a tool from arctoolbox. I have tried arcpy.AddMessage statements to see what's wrong but it just does not work.

Please help...

SCRIPT

```
# Author: George Corea, Atherton Tablelands GIS
# georgec@atgis.com.au; info@atgis.com.au

# Licence:Creative Commons

import arcpy, string, datetime, shutil, os
import arcpy.mapping as MAP

#Read input parameters from script tool
MXDList = string.split(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0), ";")
ProjectPath = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

#MXDList=r'P:\2012\183_TownPlanning_Symbology\Working\TP_Biodiversity.mxd'
#ProjectPath=r'P:\2012\183_TownPlanning_Symbology\Working'

count=0
#Loop through each MXD and print
#for MXDPath in MXDList:
#MXDFile=r'P:\2012\189_Townplanning_scheme\Working\TRC_PlanningScheme_LayoutMaster_v10.mxd'

count=count+1
arcpy.AddMessage('starting...'+str(MXDList))
##try:
for MXDFile in MXDList:

    mxd=arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(MXDFile)
    outPath = ProjectPath+'\\'+mxd.filePath[mxd.filePath.rfind('\\')+1:mxd.filePath.rfind('.')]
    arcpy.AddMessage('working on 1...'+str(mxd)+str(outPath))
    try:
        os.mkdir(outPath)
    except:
        pass
    dfList = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)
    arcpy.AddMessage('working on 2...'+str(dfList)+str(outPath))
    for df in dfList:
    #msd = outPath+'.msd'
    #arcpy.mapping.ConvertToMSD(mxd, msd, df, "NORMAL", "NORMAL")
    #arcpy.AddMessage(str(count)+'...' +str(outPath)+'...'+'\n')
        lyrList=arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", df)
        outPath = ProjectPath+'\\'+mxd.filePath[mxd.filePath.rfind('\\')+1:mxd.filePath.rfind('.')]+'\\'+str(df.name)
        #os.mkdir(outPath)
        arcpy.AddMessage('working on 3...'+str(lyrList)+str(outPath))
        for lyrFile in lyrList:
            arcpy.AddMessage(str(lyrFile))
            if lyrFile.isFeatureLayer == True:
                if lyrFile.visible == True:
                    arcpy.AddMessage(str(lyrFile)+' is visible')
                    #print str(lyrFile)+' is visible...exporting dataset'
                    outFileN=str(arcpy.ValidateTableName(lyrFile.longName[lyrFile.longName.rfind('\\')+1:]))
                    try:
                        arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(lyrFile.dataSource, outPath, outFileN)
                        arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management(lyrFile,outPath+'\\'+outFileN+'.lyr', "ABSOLUTE")
                        arcpy.LayerToKML_conversion(outPath+'\\'+outFileN+'.lyr', outPath+'\\'+outFileN+'.kmz')
                    except:
                        errorm=arcpy.GetMessages()
                        arcpy.AddMessage('Error...'+str(errorm)+' ...continuing')


            arcpy.AddMessage(str(lyrFile)+' is visible. Not Processing')
            #print str(lyrFile)+' is not visible'
    ##except:
    ##    errorM=arcpy.GetMessages()
    ##    arcpy.AddMessage(str(count)+str(errorM)+'\n continuing...\n')
    ##    print errorM
    ##    #MAP.PrintMap(MXD, printer)
    #Remove variable reference to file
    del mxd, msd
```

ERROR
[image] and that's it. The text 'working 2...' from the arcpy.AddMessages doesn't work.

When run in the Python Interpreter window you get

```
>>> import os
>>> os.getcwd()
'Q:\\scripts\\py'
>>> MXDFile=r'P:\2011\Job_031_TownPlanning_SeriesProduction\Working\mxd\Nov14_Landslide\18_TownPlanning_B&L_Overlay_Ver4a_Chillagoe.mxd'
>>> mxd=arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(MXDFile)
>>> ProjectPath=r'Q:\scripts\py\junk'
>>> outPath = ProjectPath+'\\'+mxd.filePath[mxd.filePath.rfind('\\')+1:mxd.filePath.rfind('.')]
>>> dfList = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)
>>> for df in dfList:
...     lyrList=arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", df)
...     print lyrList
...     
[<map group layer u'Residences'>, <map layer u'Residential Structure'>, <map layer u'Residential Structure'>, <map group layer u'Base_Top'>, <map layer u'Regional Activity Centre'>, <map layer u'Homesteads'>, <map layer u'State Controlled Road'>, <map layer u'Local Road'>, <map layer u'Local Road'>, <map layer u'Wetland'>, <map layer u'Waterbody'>, <map layer u'Protected Area'>, <map layer u'TRC Boundary'>, <map layer u'Property Boundary'>, <map layer u'Watercourse'>, <map layer u'Tri_RiversTRCClip'>, <map layer u'Rural_DrainageTRCClip'>, <map group layer u'Hazard'>, <map group layer u'NewLandslide'>, <map layer u'100k_trc_tiles_TVM'>, <map layer u'BULLOCK_CREEK'>, <map layer u'BULIMBA'>, <map layer u'BLACKDOWN'>, <map layer u'BELLEVUE'>, <map layer u'MAYTOWN'>, <map layer u'M_SURPRISE'>, <map layer u'LYNDBROOK'>, <map layer u'KIRRAMA'>, <map layer u'KINGFISH'>, <map layer u'HIGHBURY'>, <map layer u'CASHMERE'>, <map layer u'CAIRNS'>, <map layer u'MUNGANA'>, <map layer u'MOUNT'>, <map layer u'MOSSMAN'>, <map layer u'GALLOWAY'>, <map layer u'CONJUBOY'>, <map layer u'CHILLAGOE'>, <map layer u'BARTLE_FRERE'>, <map layer u'ATHERTON'>, <map layer u'ABINGDON_DOWNS'>, <map layer u'WALSH'>, <map layer u'WALLABADAH'>, <map layer u'VALLEY_LAGOONS'>, <map layer u'TULLY'>, <map layer u'STRATHMORE'>, <map layer u'ST_RONANS'>, <map layer u'SOUTH'>, <map layer u'RUMULA'>, <map layer u'RAVENSHOE'>, <map layer u'Landslide Zone'>, <map layer u'High Bushfire Hazard'>, <map layer u'High Bushfire Hazard Buffer '>, <map layer u'Medium Bushfire Hazard'>, <map layer u'Medium Bushfire Hazard Buffer'>, <map group layer u'Base_Bottom'>, <map layer u'Protected Area'>]
[<map group layer u'Residences'>, <map layer u'Residential Structure'>, <map layer u'Residential Structure'>, <map group layer u'Base_Top'>, <map layer u'Regional Activity Centre'>, <map layer u'Homesteads'>, <map layer u'State Controlled Road'>, <map layer u'Local Road'>, <map layer u'Local Road'>, <map layer u'Wetland'>, <map layer u'Waterbody'>, <map layer u'Protected Area'>, <map layer u'TRC Boundary'>, <map layer u'Property Boundary'>, <map layer u'River'>, <map layer u'Tri_RiversTRCClip'>, <map layer u'Rural_DrainageTRCClip'>, <map group layer u'Hazard'>, <map group layer u'NewLandslide'>, <map layer u'100k_trc_tiles_TVM'>, <map layer u'BULLOCK_CREEK'>, <map layer u'BULIMBA'>, <map layer u'BLACKDOWN'>, <map layer u'BELLEVUE'>, <map layer u'MAYTOWN'>, <map layer u'M_SURPRISE'>, <map layer u'LYNDBROOK'>, <map layer u'KIRRAMA'>, <map layer u'KINGFISH'>, <map layer u'HIGHBURY'>, <map layer u'CASHMERE'>, <map layer u'CAIRNS'>, <map layer u'MUNGANA'>, <map layer u'MOUNT'>, <map layer u'MOSSMAN'>, <map layer u'GALLOWAY'>, <map layer u'CONJUBOY'>, <map layer u'CHILLAGOE'>, <map layer u'BARTLE_FRERE'>, <map layer u'ATHERTON'>, <map layer u'ABINGDON_DOWNS'>, <map layer u'WALSH'>, <map layer u'WALLABADAH'>, <map layer u'VALLEY_LAGOONS'>, <map layer u'TULLY'>, <map layer u'STRATHMORE'>, <map layer u'ST_RONANS'>, <map layer u'SOUTH'>, <map layer u'RUMULA'>, <map layer u'RAVENSHOE'>, <map layer u'Landslide Zone'>, <map layer u'High Bushfire Hazard'>, <map layer u'High Bushfire Hazard Buffer '>, <map layer u'Medium Bushfire Hazard'>, <map layer u'Medium Bushfire Hazard Buffer'>, <map group layer u'Base_Bottom'>, <map layer u'Protected Area'>]
[<map layer u'Regional Activity Centre'>, <map layer u'State Controlled Road'>, <map layer u'Frame_Extents2'>, <map layer u'TRC Boundary'>]
>>>
```

TOOL PARAMS
[image]

**=== RESPONSE to Answers/Comments in post ===**

```
Messages
Executing: InvestigateMXDs P:\2012\096_CCRC_2_Biodiversity\Working\BiodiversityOverlay_70k_Series3b.mxd D:\junk
Start Time: Mon Aug 06 09:01:22 2012
Running script InvestigateMXDs...
Now processing ...
  Map: P:\2012\096_CCRC_2_Biodiversity\Working\BiodiversityOverlay_70k_Series3b.mxd
```

So basically it hangs on the df list. There is no further error message even if you try to capture it.

Test on simple mxd is below. Note that this works fine when run as a python script directly.

[image]

```
Messages
Executing: InvestigateMXDs P:\2012\183_TownPlanning_Symbology\Working\test.mxd P:\2012\183_TownPlanning_Symbology\Working\junk
Start Time: Tue Aug 07 09:11:35 2012
Running script InvestigateMXDs...
Now processing ...
  Map: P:\2012\183_TownPlanning_Symbology\Working\test.mxd
```

When run as a python we get the following in less than 30s

> > > 

```
starting...['test.mxd']
working on 1...<geoprocessing Map object object at 0x029471E0>P:\2012\183_TownPlanning_Symbology\Working\test

working on 2...[<DataFrame object at 0xee12950[0xee22fc0]>]P:\2012\183_TownPlanning_Symbology\Working\test
working on 3...in: P:\2012\183_TownPlanning_Symbology\Working\test\Layers
TRC_Boundary is visible PROCESSING...
TRC_Boundary is not visible. Not Processing
Map_Extents is visible PROCESSING...
Map_Extents is not visible. Not Processing
```

and directory structure
[image]

**##Issue with modified script from Polygeo**
Same problems.

[image]
**=== END Response ===**

Comment: I'm not in a position to test at the moment but if it works without a tool dialog but not with one then I would focus on the tool parameters and the variables set using GetParameterAsText are processed.  Perhaps "gut" a test copy of your Python script and try to get it to process the list of MXDs doing something trivial successfully before restoring the "bells and whistles".

Comment: Thanks. I have tried but as in the screen capture it just fails after reading the data frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it again by using a new script tool -till now I was just changing the link to the python script from the old tool. Now it works fine. For anyone interested the updated code and tool set up is below.

```
# Copies, clips and creates symbology of all visibile layers in mxd's in the current directory. Also creates a text file with metadata for use.
# Author: George Corea, Atherton Tablelands GIS
# georgec@atgis.com.au; info@atgis.com.au

# Licence:Creative Commons

import arcpy, string, datetime, shutil, os, glob
import arcpy.mapping as MAP

arcpy.env.workspace = os.getcwd()
arcpy.env.outputCoordinateSystem=r'L:\Vector_Data\Administrative\Boundaries\Local_Govt\TRC\trc_boundary_Polygon.prj' #to maintain all datasets in the same projection
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

MXDList=string.split(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0), ";")
ProjectPath=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

rootPath=ProjectPath
#MXDList=glob.glob('*.mxd')
#ProjectPath=r'P:\2012\183_TownPlanning_Symbology\Working' # root output directory
clip_features=r'L:\Vector_Data\Administrative\Boundaries\Local_Govt\TRC\trc_boundary_Polygon.shp' # polygon to clip data to AOI
AOI='_trc' #appended as suffix to dataset
xy_tolerance=1 #clip tolerance

# No edits should be required below this line.

VisibleLyrList = []
count=1


def layer_details(outPath, outFileN, lyrFile, type): #Generates the metadata

    descLayer = arcpy.Describe(lyrFile.dataSource)
    ReviewLog=outPath+'\\'+type+'_'+outFileN+'_log.txt'
    f = open(ReviewLog, 'a')
    f.write(str(lyrFile.name)+': name{'+str(lyrFile.datasetName)+\
    '}; query{'+str(lyrFile.definitionQuery)+\
    '}; source{'+str(lyrFile.dataSource)+\
    '}; description{'+str(lyrFile.description)+\
    '}; symbology{'+ str(lyrFile.symbologyType)+\
    '}; original projection{'+str(descLayer.spatialReference.name)+\
    '}; extent(x,y){'+str(descLayer.extent.XMax)+','+str(descLayer.extent.XMin)+','+str(descLayer.extent.YMax)+','+str(descLayer.extent.YMin)+\
    '}; format{'+str(descLayer.shapeType)+\
    '}; size(bytes) ~{'+str(os.path.getsize(lyrFile.dataSource))+\
    '} @{'+str(datetime.datetime.now())+'}'\
    )
    f.close()



print 'starting...'+str(MXDList)

for MXDFile in MXDList:

    mxd=arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(MXDFile)
    outPath = ProjectPath+'\\'+mxd.filePath[mxd.filePath.rfind('\\')+1:mxd.filePath.rfind('.')]
    arcpy.AddMessage ('Working on file #' + str(count) +' ...'+str(mxd.filePath))
    try:
        os.mkdir(outPath)
    except:
        pass
    dfList = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)
    #print arcpy.GetMessages()
    #print 'working on 2...'+str(dfList)+str(outPath)

    for df in dfList:
    #msd = outPath+'.msd'
    #arcpy.mapping.ConvertToMSD(mxd, msd, df, "NORMAL", "NORMAL")
    #print (str(count)+'...' +str(outPath)+'...'+'\n')
        arcpy.AddMessage ('Working on dataframe ... ' +str(df.name))
        lyrList=arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", df)
        outPath = ProjectPath+'\\'+mxd.filePath[mxd.filePath.rfind('\\')+1:mxd.filePath.rfind('.')]+'\\'+str(df.name)
        try:
            os.mkdir(outPath)
        except:
            pass
        print ('working on 3...in: '+str(outPath))
        for lyrFile in lyrList:
            #print (str(lyrFile))
            if lyrFile.isFeatureLayer == True:
                if lyrFile.visible == True:
                    if lyrFile.name not in VisibleLyrList:
                        VisibleLyrList.append(lyrFile.name)
                        arcpy.AddMessage (str(lyrFile)+' is visible PROCESSING...')
                        outFileN=str(arcpy.ValidateTableName(lyrFile.longName[lyrFile.longName.rfind('\\')+1:]))
                        try:
                            rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(lyrFile.dataSource)
                            row = rows.next()
                            if row:
                                arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(lyrFile.dataSource, outPath, outFileN)
                                #arcpy.Copy_management(lyrFile.dataSource, outPath+'//'+outFileN, "")
                                arcpy.Clip_analysis(outPath+'\\'+outFileN+'.shp', clip_features, outPath+'\\'+outFileN+AOI+'.shp', xy_tolerance)
                                #updateLayer = outPath+'\\'+outFileN+'.lyr'
                                sourceLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(outPath+'\\'+outFileN+'.shp')
                                sourceLayer_AOI = arcpy.mapping.Layer(outPath+'\\'+outFileN+AOI+'.shp')
                                #arcpy.mapping.UpdateLayer(df, updateLayer, sourceLayer, True)
                                arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management(lyrFile,outPath+'\\'+outFileN+'_sym.lyr', "ABSOLUTE")
                                arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management(sourceLayer_AOI,outPath+'\\'+outFileN+AOI+'.lyr', "ABSOLUTE")
                                arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management (outPath+'\\'+outFileN+AOI+'.lyr', outPath+'\\'+outFileN+'_sym.lyr')
                                descLayer = arcpy.Describe(sourceLayer)
                                layer_details(outPath, outFileN, lyrFile,"COMPLETED")
                                arcpy.Delete_management(outPath+'\\'+outFileN+'_sym.lyr')
                                arcpy.Delete_management(outPath+'\\'+outFileN+'.shp')

                                #arcpy.LayerToKML_conversion(outPath+'\\'+outFileN+'.lyr', outPath+'\\'+outFileN+'.kmz')
                            else:
                                arcpy.AddMessage ("!!!Datasource Issue!!!...continuing")
                                layer_details(outPath, outFileN,lyrFile,"ISSUE")
                                IssueLog=rootPath+'\\'+'Issue_log.txt'
                                f = open(IssueLog, 'a')
                                f.write(str(lyrFile.name)+': name{'+str(lyrFile.datasetName)+ '}; source{'+str(lyrFile.dataSource)+'}'+'\n')
                                f.close()
                        except:
                            errorm=arcpy.GetMessages()
                            arcpy.AddMessage ('!!! ERROR !!!!...'+str(errorm)+' ...continuing')
                            layer_details(outPath, outFileN, lyrFile,"ERROR")
                            #break
                            ErrorLog=rootPath+'\\'+'Error_log.txt'
                            f = open(ErrorLog, 'a')
                            f.write(str(lyrFile.name)+': name{'+str(lyrFile.datasetName)+ '}; source{'+str(lyrFile.dataSource)+'}'+'\n')
                            f.close()


                        else:
                            pass
                    else:
                        arcpy.AddMessage (str(lyrFile)+' Is NOT Visible. Not Processing')
                else:
                    arcpy.AddMessage (str(lyrFile)+' Is NOT Feature Layer. Not Processing')
        count=count+1
            #print str(lyrFile)+' is not visible'

    #Remove variable reference to file
    del mxd, outPath, lyrFile
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like your MXDList is now coming as data type File rather than ArcMap Document.  Is it still a Multivalue and filtered by *.mxd to make for easy selection?  Anyway, I'm glad its now working.

Answer (score 0):

This is far from a complete Answer as yet, but if you put the test script below behind your existing tool dialog (with its multivalue ArcMap Document parameter), will it run and list all your chosen maps, with their data frames and layers?  If it does then the shell works and we can start to look more closely at what it needs to be done with each data frame object the script creates.

```
import arcpy

MXDList = str(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)).split(";")
arcpy.AddMessage("Now processing ...")
arcpy.AddMessage("MXDList of: " + str(MXDList))
for MXDFile in MXDList:
    MXDFile = MXDFile.strip("'")
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(str(MXDFile))
    arcpy.AddMessage("  Map: " + mxd.filePath)
    dfList = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)
    for df in dfList:
        arcpy.AddMessage("    Data frame: " + df.name)
        lyrList = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd,"*",df)
        for lyr in lyrList:
            arcpy.AddMessage("      Layer: " + lyr.name)
```

Comment: Thanks....nope still doesn't work. I have updated your answer with the message I get.

Comment: That's weird, but at least gives another angle to investigate from.  Is there any chance that when the df line hangs, that it is not just slow rather than halted?  Does the code work when you choose one or two of the simplest MXDs you have on your system?  If it works for simple MXDs (like it does for me) then maybe we need to see what is special about the ones you are working with.

Comment: sorry...same issue. See edits.\

Comment: I've not had responses edited into my Answer before and am thinking that may make it confusing.  Would it work for you to take your response out into a separate Answer that just you Edit?  For now I've updated my test script so that it reports the MXDList being processed and lets me see what you are getting back from the tool dialog.

Comment: Sorry about this. I haven't done this before either and I'll chalk it up to an experiment that didn't work.

Comment: No problem - experimentation is good - but I think keeping my suggestions separate from what you are seeing in response will keep things easier to follow